# How can I store an unsigned 64 bit value in two signed integers and recover them?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

If I have a `uint64_t original` and two regular four byte ints, (which are signed), I would like to store the value in the two ints and recover the unsigned 64 byte later. This should be possible because we have 64 bits available in both cases. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
uint64_t test = 1350640807215539000;
int a = test >> 32; //get top 32 bits
int b = test & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF; //keep bottom 32 bits

uint64_t recover_test = ((a << 32) & b);
```

but this isn't giving me back the original value of test...what part am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use OR instead of AND. Furthermore i guess you need to convert `a` to 64bit before shifting (but i'm not sure on that)

Comment: Yup I needed to promote, some people seem to not be finding this to work though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing a lot of error-prone bit-twiddling you could just use a union:

```
union
{
    uint64_t u64;
    int32_t s32[2];
} u;

u.u64 = 1350640807215539000ULL;

printf("a = %d\n", u.s32[0]);
printf("b = %d\n", u.s32[1]);
```

Comment: @Alexey: I think it's only theoretically UB if you write to one type in a union and then read back from an incompatible type, but even this kind of usage is so widespread that it has to be supported by any self-respecting compiler. I am not a C language lawyer though so I could be proved wrong on this.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze As far as I know, this is the idiomatic way to do the wanted conversion. But, I'd be glad to learn otherwise if I'm wrong.

Comment: @HonkyTonk C99 J.1 Unspecified behavior: The value of a union member other than the last one stored into. One needs to dig up their compiler documentation (or source code) to see whether this trick is OK with their compiler or not.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
uint64_t test = 1350640807215539000;
int32_t a = test >> 32; //get top 32 bits
int32_t b = test & 0xffffffff; //keep bottom 32 bits
uint64_t recover_test = (((uint64_t)(uint32_t)a << 32) | (uint32_t)b);
```

Notice you have made the mistake of not casting `a` when "recovering" - you need to do that otherwise shifting 32 will make the value all "drop off" the left as it's not big enough. Also you were AND-ing rather than OR-ing the two parts together.

Comment: This code does not answer the request of storing the value in two signed 32-bit integers.

Comment: Yes this seems to be working for me when `a` and `b` are regular ints as well.

Comment: Using this code with a and b changed to signed 32-bit integers works for the specific example value in the question, but it does not work in general. It does not work when b is negative.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista: I executed this code with test set to 0x92be70a89d3aa338. It produced 0xffffffff9d3aa338 in `recover_test`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Matt, its because you need to intermediately cast an int to uint32_t to account for the sign bit, otherwise it gets misinterpreted due to the way the number is stored.

Comment: Your version is overkill. You just need: ((((u64)a) << 32) | (u32)b);

Comment: The revised version works on most platforms. The only remaining issue I see is that the assignments to a and b may overflow, which is implementation-defined according to the C standard.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista need the intermediate cast to `uint32_t` to fix a problem where `a` or `b` were negative.

Comment: @mattjgalloway You need the intermediate `uint32_t` for `b`, but for `a`, the shift will drop the leading 1 bits.

Comment: You don't need the u64 cast for b is my point. You can | a u32 into a u64 without the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
uint64_t recover_test = ((((uint64_t)a) << 32) | (uint32_t)b);
```

You need to tell the compiler to promote the a to a 64bit number first - and then do the shift. Otherwise it shifts inside a 32 bit value - dumping the high bits.

@edit: Wow. So if b is signed, | with a signed 32 bit value will promote the signed bit from the top of b, to the top bit of a after it is cast to 64 bits. So you need to first cast b to unsigned before the |.

Comment: Some people are quick on the downmod. The code had two errors. Original answer fixed one. i update the answer to fix both errors.

Comment: There are three errors, not two. This code does not fix the problem that occurs when b is negative.

Comment: Yes it was | instead of & too

Comment: @eric: there are two errors. not three. It works with a and b being signed. | and << operators could care less about the sign bit.

Comment: When this code is executed with `test` set to 0x92be70a89d3aa338 instead of the example value in the question, the result in `recover_test` is 0xffffffff9d3aa338, which is incorrect.

Comment: eric: You're right. I was confused for a bit. I fixed it again. See the edit.

Comment: The revised version works on most platforms. The only remaining issue I see is that the assignments to a and b may overflow, which is implementation-defined according to the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

You may be unable to do this in a fully portable way.

The reason is that N-bit signed ints may only be good enough for representing 2<sup>N</sup>-1 distinct values.

This is especially the case if signed integers are in the sign-and-magnitude or the 1's-complement representation. These representations are are symmetric around 0.

Even the 2's-complement representation may be symmetric around 0 and allow only 2<sup>N</sup>-1 distinct values from -(2<sup>N-1</sup>-1) to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1 (just like in the above case) instead of allowing 2<sup>N</sup> distinct values from -2<sup>N-1</sup> to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1.

Further, union tricks and forceful shoving of N-bit unsigned integers into N-bit signed integers do or can result in undefined behavior per the C standard. You want to avoid that.

You can do something like this, but it may fail on some platforms:

```
#include <limits.h>

#if UINT_MAX >= 0xFFFFFFFF
typedef unsigned uint32;
#define UINT32_MIN UINT_MIN
#define UINT32_MAX UINT_MAX
typedef int int32;
#define INT32_MIN INT_MIN
#define INT32_MAX INT_MAX
#else
typedef unsigned long uint32;
#define UINT32_MIN ULONG_MIN
#define UINT32_MAX ULONG_MAX
typedef long int32;
#define INT32_MIN LONG_MIN
#define INT32_MAX LONG_MAX
#endif

typedef unsigned long long uint64;
#define UINT64_MAX ULLONG_MAX

#ifndef C_ASSERT
#define C_ASSERT(expr) extern char CAssertExtern[(expr)?1:-1]
#endif

// Make sure uint32 is 32 bits exactly without padding bits:
C_ASSERT(sizeof(uint32) * CHAR_BIT == 32 && UINT32_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFF);

// Make sure int32 is 32 bits exactly without padding bits and is 2's complement:
C_ASSERT(sizeof(int32) * CHAR_BIT == 32 &&
         INT32_MAX == 0x7FFFFFFF && (uint32)INT32_MIN == 0x80000000);

// Make sure uint64 is 64 bits exactly without padding bits:
C_ASSERT(sizeof(uint64) * CHAR_BIT == 64 && UINT64_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL);

void splitUint64IntoInt32s(uint64 x, int32* ph, int32* pl)
{
  uint32 h = (uint32)(x >> 32);
  uint32 l = (uint32)x;
  if (h <= INT32_MAX)
    *ph = h;
  else
    *ph = (int)(h - INT32_MAX - 1) - INT32_MAX - 1;
  if (l <= INT32_MAX)
    *pl = l;
  else
    *pl = (int)(l - INT32_MAX - 1) - INT32_MAX - 1;
}

uint64 combineInt32sIntoUint64(int32 h, int32 l)
{
  return ((uint64)(uint32)h << 32) | (uint32)l;
}
```

gcc is able to produce quite optimal machine code from the above without any arithmetic operations:

```
_splitUint64IntoInt32s:
        movl    8(%esp), %edx
        movl    12(%esp), %eax
        movl    %edx, (%eax)
        movl    4(%esp), %edx
        movl    16(%esp), %eax
        movl    %edx, (%eax)
        ret

_combineInt32sIntoUint64:
        movl    8(%esp), %eax
        movl    4(%esp), %edx
        ret
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long u64 = 0xAAAAAAAABBBBBBBB;
int l = ((int*)(&u64))[0];
int h = ((int*)(&u64))[1];
unsigned long long restored;
((int*)(&restored))[0] = l;
((int*)(&restored))[1] = h;
```

Answer (score 0):

> what part am I doing wrong?

```
uint64_t recover_test = ((a << 32) & b);
```

`a << 32` is undefined behavior.

Bitwise left shifting more or the the same as the width in bits of the left operand is undefined.

Comment: Casting `a` to `uint64_t` before shifting is insufficient to fix this code.

Comment: 32 is equal to the width in bits, not more than it.  One of those statements must be incorrect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I never said it is sufficient, I pinpointed an issue in his program. If you downvoted you should admit there is nothing wrong in this answer.

Comment: There is something wrong with this answer: It does not answer the question, which is “How can I store an unsigned 64-bit value in two unsigned integers and recover [it]?”

Comment: @EricPostpischil there are several questions in the OP post. I'm free to answer one of his questions or to point one of the issues of his program. Downvoting is unfair.

Comment: @ouah: If you want a favorable vote, you could improve the answer. Nobody has yet provided an answer that is both correct and complete under the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What's the problem with PaulR's?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm fine with the `(((uint64_t) a << 32) | (uint32_t) b)` solution. Now regarding the implementation defined conversions to `int` in `a` and `b` declarations, the OP just should use unsigned types. C explicitly advises (C99, 6.5p4) to use unsigned operand for bitwise operations.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Mostly the problem is I overlooked it. I think it may be fine, although I am looking for loopholes in the C standard. Oddly, the standard specifies that int32_t has no padding and is two’s complement, but I do not see that it eliminates the overflow problem. So the union would work (as in PaulR’s answer) but directly assigning to an int32_t (as in other answers) could have problems.

Comment: @ouah: A response to the question “How do I do X with signed integers” that says “Use unsigned integers” does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t test = 1350640807215539000;
    int a = test >> 32; //get top 32 bits
    int b = test & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF; //keep bottom 32 bits

    uint64_t recover_test = (((uint64_t)((uint32_t)a) << 32) | (uint32_t)b);


    printf("a: %llu\n", (uint64_t)a);
    printf("b: %llu\n", (uint64_t)b);
    printf("Recovered: %llu\n", recover_test);

    printf("Test %s\n", test == recover_test ? "PASSED" : "FAILED");
}
```

Mostly the same as all the other ones, I just explicitly convert the ints back to unsigned ints prior to using them anywhere.  This could important if either `a` or `b` end up being negative.

Output:

```
a: 314470568
b: 2100994872
Recovered: 1350640807215539000
Test PASSED
```

Output when b is negative (Thanks Daniel):

```
a: 314470568
b: 18446744073663062840    # -46488776
Recovered: 1350640809363022648
Test PASSED
```

Comment: This will _very probably_ fail on 1350640809363022648.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It does fail; I tested it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, it _must_ fail indeed (before the correction), only the way it fails is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Implementation-defined (may raise an implementation-defined signal), 6.3.1.3 (3).

Comment: The revised version works on most platforms. The only remaining issue I see is that the assignments to a and b may overflow, which is implementation-defined according to the C standard.